# JSON deserialization with GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

Im using gson to deserializate my data, but something gone wrong. I don't know what.

Json script looks like this

```
[{"cat_id":"1","cat_name":"lol"},{"cat_id":"2","cat_name":"xd"}]
```

Comment: Post your `Category` class.

Comment: There is a discrepancy between the json and the fields on the class.  Please provide both the class and the actual json.

Comment: json was just an example, i paste my Category class, and correct json. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Do you receive a stack trace?

Comment: here is my log from logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
List<Category> videos = g1.fromJson(myDownloadedJson, new TypeToken<List<Category>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: In this case post your class Category as asked by Kevin

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(c.get(i).cat_name);
}
```

The `Category` class does not contain a field `c_name`, I believe you meant to print out the value of the `cat_name` field.

Comment: still null pointer, i want to read all items names from c list and i don't know why it throws null pointer.. becouse the json is correct..
I know it's not so easy.. :P